# STM32F091 CAN does not transmit (also, example uses nonexistent functions???)

Tags: can-bus, stm32f0

I have a STM32F091RCT board that I am trying to coerce into serving as an improvised CAN node. To have a starting point, I looked up some code examples. I started with [this one](https://mieurekas.blogspot.com/2017/10/stm32f0-can-bus-hal-example.html%60), but it references some typedefs (such as `CanTxMsgTypeDef`) and functions (`HAL_CAN_Transmit`, for example), that seem not to exist in the `stm32f0xx_hal_can.h` header. So instead I went with an example intended for F103, and ended up with this code (autogenerated comments and CAN-unrelated stuff removed):

```
CAN_HandleTypeDef hcan;

// other peripheral configuration, etc.

static void MX_CAN_Init(void)
{

  hcan.Instance = CAN;
  hcan.Init.Prescaler = 16;
  hcan.Init.Mode = CAN_MODE_LOOPBACK;      // also tried normal mode, same deal
  hcan.Init.SyncJumpWidth = CAN_SJW_1TQ;
  hcan.Init.TimeSeg1 = CAN_BS1_1TQ;
  hcan.Init.TimeSeg2 = CAN_BS2_1TQ;
  hcan.Init.TimeTriggeredMode = DISABLE;
  hcan.Init.AutoBusOff = DISABLE;
  hcan.Init.AutoWakeUp = DISABLE;
  hcan.Init.AutoRetransmission = DISABLE;
  hcan.Init.ReceiveFifoLocked = DISABLE;
  hcan.Init.TransmitFifoPriority = DISABLE;


  if (HAL_CAN_Init(&hcan) != HAL_OK)
  {
    Error_Handler();
  }

  CAN_FilterTypeDef sf;
    sf.FilterMaskIdHigh = 0x0000;
    sf.FilterMaskIdLow = 0x0000;
    sf.FilterFIFOAssignment = CAN_FILTER_FIFO0;
    sf.FilterBank = 0;
    sf.FilterMode = CAN_FILTERMODE_IDMASK;
    sf.FilterScale = CAN_FILTERSCALE_32BIT;
    sf.FilterActivation = CAN_FILTER_ENABLE;
    if (HAL_CAN_ConfigFilter(&hcan, &sf) != HAL_OK) {
      Error_Handler();

    }

    if (HAL_CAN_ConfigFilter(&hcan, &sf) != HAL_OK)
        Error_Handler();

//           this didn't want to work
//    if (HAL_CAN_RegisterCallback(&hcan, HAL_CAN_RX_FIFO0_MSG_PENDING_CB_ID, can_irq)) {
//      Error_Handler();
//    }

    if (HAL_CAN_Start(&hcan) != HAL_OK) {
      Error_Handler();
    }

    if (HAL_CAN_ActivateNotification(&hcan, CAN_IT_RX_FIFO0_MSG_PENDING) != HAL_OK) {
      Error_Handler();
    }

}

void can_irq(CAN_HandleTypeDef *pcan) {
  CAN_RxHeaderTypeDef msg;
  uint8_t data[8];
  HAL_CAN_GetRxMessage(pcan, CAN_RX_FIFO0, &msg, data);
  // do something
}

// ...

int main(void)
{
  HAL_Init();

  SystemClock_Config();

  /* Initialize all configured peripherals */
  MX_GPIO_Init();
  MX_DMA_Init();
  MX_I2C1_Init();
  MX_USART1_UART_Init();
  MX_TIM1_Init();
  MX_CAN_Init();

  while (1)
  {
        uint32_t mb;
        CAN_TxHeaderTypeDef msg;
        uint8_t data[] = "Hello!";

        msg.StdId = 127;
        msg.IDE = CAN_ID_STD;
        msg.RTR = CAN_RTR_DATA;
        msg.DLC = 6;
        msg.TransmitGlobalTime = DISABLE;

        if (HAL_CAN_AddTxMessage(&hcan, &msg, data, &mb) != HAL_OK) {
          Error_Handler();
        }
  }
}

void send_CAN_test_message(void)
{
    uint32_t mb;
    CAN_TxHeaderTypeDef msg;
    uint8_t data[] = "Hello!";

    msg.StdId = 127;
    msg.IDE = CAN_ID_STD;
    msg.RTR = CAN_RTR_DATA;
    msg.DLC = 6;
    msg.TransmitGlobalTime = DISABLE;

    if (HAL_CAN_AddTxMessage(&hcan, &msg, data, &mb) != HAL_OK) {
      Error_Handler();
    }
}
```

So I would expect this to transmit a message over the CAN bus every iteration of the main loop. Unfortunately, that seems not to be the case, as an oscilloscope connected to the CAN_TX pin (also tried RX for a good measure) only shows the voltage rise from 0 V to 3.3 V when the `MX_CAN_Init()` gets executed. For clarification, I am measuring signals straight out of the MCU, **before** the transceiver (MCP2551).

I have a suspicion I'm missing something very obvious here....would anyone happen to know what that very obvious thing is? Perhaps a pseudo-conflict on the controller pins (discrepancy between TX and RX), and the controller is just waiting it out indefinitely?

Comment: Do you have an actual CAN bus? Otherwise it won't work. [What are the most common causes of CAN bus communication errors?](https://electrical.codidact.com/posts/276251)

Comment: Wouldn't the loopback mode let a single node work on its own?

Comment: In loopback mode you usually don't see anything on the bus. Anyway, at a glance your timing settings seem very strange. What's `CAN_BS1_1TQ`? If that means 1 TQ then obviously nothing won't work since your baudrate and sync settings don't make any sense.

Answer (score 0):

A little late to the party, but I found the CAN_MCR->DBF flag. It's by default set to 1 and is defined like this:

Bit 16 DBF: Debug freeze
0: CAN working during debug
1: CAN reception/transmission frozen during debug. Reception FIFOs can still be accessed/controlled normally.

So if you have the debugger running, the can bus will be DEAD. Pretty annoying when you don't know it...